# AWS Device Farm ignoring TestNG Priority annotations

Tags: testng, appium-android, aws-device-farm

I have created one test suite class with `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods are declared under `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations.

I have included 6 test cases in this class with `@Test(priority = #)` for each test cases. I execute this class on my local machine and it works fine but when I upload it on AWS Device Farm it executes only one test case with (priority=1) and for all the other test cases device farm in initializing appium server.

How to overcome this blocker?

Comment: Here some example https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app/issues/15

Comment: Din't work..for every @Test annotation in a class AWS Device Farm is invoking new appium instance.

Comment: Can you please review the answers and let us know if there are any questions

Comment: I have created a AndroidBaseUtil Class with all the desired capabilities defined under it and extended that class in my suite class. Also in @BeforeTest I am calling helper class for login..The helper class also extends AndroidBaseUtil Class.. Is it due to this its creating problem?

Comment: Without the logs it's not possible to tell. Generally speaking, no that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Any update on those logs?

Comment: Hello, any update on those logs? Did I answer the question?

Comment: Is this issue resolve now? Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the custom environment? This limitation can be expected with the standard environment.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/xml-file-tests-jar-file-device-farm/

> Note: In Device Farm's standard environment only a subset of features are supported for the testng.xml file. If priority, the include tag, the exclude tag, complex grouping, or using parameters from the testng.xml file are required for the project, then use the custom environments.

[Edit]

I tested priority using the sample apps and tests

```
git clone https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app.git
cd aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app/
mkdir ./src/test/resources
// I used VS code here but any text editor will work
code ./src/test/resources/testng.xml
```

Then I added the code some the above support link so that I don't haft to run through all the tests:

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite">
    <test name="test">
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.LoginTest"/> <!--Package.ClassName-->
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Then I modified the LoginTest to use the [priority feature](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) of TestNG.

**LoginTest.java**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014-2016 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 * http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

package Tests;

import Pages.LoginPage;
import Tests.AbstractBaseTests.TestBase;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * Tests for a login page
 */
public class LoginTest extends TestBase {
    private static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS_MESSAGE = "You are logged on as admin";
    private static final String LOGIN_FAIL_MESSAGE = "You gave me the wrong username and password";
    private static final String CORRECT_USER_NAME = "admin";
    private static final String CORRECT_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String FAIL_USER_NAME = "Wrong User";
    private static final String FAIL_PASSWORD = "12345";
    private static final String BAD_TEXT_ENTRY_MSG = "Username sent to text field incorrectly";

    private LoginPage loginPage;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Login Page";
    }

    /**
     * Creates a login
     */
    @BeforeTest
    @Override
    public void setUpPage() {
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    }

    /**
     * Tests logging in with valid credentials by verifying if the login message is correct
     */
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void loginSuccess() throws InterruptedException {
        Assert.assertTrue(loginPage.login(CORRECT_USER_NAME, CORRECT_PASSWORD), BAD_TEXT_ENTRY_MSG);
        Assert.assertEquals(loginPage.getMessage(), LOGIN_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Tests logging in with invalid credentials by verifying if the error message is correct
     */
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void loginFail() throws InterruptedException {
        Assert.assertTrue(loginPage.login(FAIL_USER_NAME, FAIL_PASSWORD), BAD_TEXT_ENTRY_MSG);
        Assert.assertEquals(loginPage.getMessage(), LOGIN_FAIL_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * After each test method, logout or try again
     */
    @AfterMethod
    public void logOut() {
        loginPage.pressAltButton();
        Assert.assertTrue(loginPage.checkIfBackAtLogin());
    }
}
```

I packaged the tests using the command `mvn clean package -DskipTests=true`

Running this in device farm yielded the following results:

[image: scheduling run]

video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/incI1.jpg

[image: customer artifacts]

[image: results]

So I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Can you provide evidence of Device Farm's custom environment failing to execute with priority?

Comment: Yes I am using custom environment having Appium 1.7.2